# Switch Microsoft Office user interface language to English

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language, regional-settings

I have this big problem, that Office 365 switched to Polish user interface some time ago.
And the problem is, that I cannot set it back to English, no matter what I do.
I'm Polish and I've paid for Office 365 in Polish currency using a credit card from a Polish bank.
But I desperately need my Office 365 in English.
My goal is to set English user interface in Microsoft Office 365, to have English formula's names in Excel and English menus in Office 365.

The operating system was installed with Polish language but is now switched to English.

I've tried in the Office 365 language preferences dialog, but Office 365 doesn't follow these settings.

There was over 1 year period, from June 2021 when I've bought my laptop and installed Office 365 on it, when Office 365 was in English, but around 2022/2023 (maybe earlier - I'm not sure) the Office 365 switched interface language into Polish against my will.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you uninstall Office and then reinstall it? I can tell you part of the reason Office is in Polish is due to the fact you have set your regional local to Polish instead of English.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-editing-or-authoring-language-or-set-language-preferences-in-office-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d) should help

Comment: @Ramhound In the link you provided is nothing I haven't already done and what I haven't shown on the print screens. The display language is installed and set to English.
But the ribbon and all menus, all Excel formula names are in Polish. And I need English.

Comment: Try my original suggestion of uninstalling and reinstalling Office, after changing, your locale. I don’t know what you mean by “but Office 365 doesn't follow these settings.”

Comment: As long as you installed a Language Interface Pack [LIP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-microsoft-365-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOffice-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1) you should be able to change the interface that doesn’t mean that Windows won’t attempt to change it back due to your region.

Comment: @Ramhound Regional format is very important for me to stay as ```Polish```. Dates are formatted differently in Poland than in U.S. And I want them formatted using ```Polish``` setting for example DD-MM-YYYY for dates. The same with time. I need 24h time format. The same with coma being decimal separator and " " being thousands and millions separator. I want English interface and ribbon, but not U.S. settings.

Comment: Can you at least temporarily test my suggestion?

Comment: I sugget you re-install English language package from the link provided from Ramhound.

Comment: @Ramhound You can write an answer for this question, because after I've downloaded English (United States) Language Interface Pack from the link you've provided, the Office Display Language changed into English. Although I've also switched both ```Country or Region``` and ```Regional Format``` in Settings into English (United States).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this big problem, that Office 365 switched to Polish user interface some time ago. And the problem is that I cannot set it back to English, no matter what I do.

My suggestion is to simply reinstall the English Language Accessory Pack (LAP) located [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-microsoft-365-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOffice-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1)

Comment: Language Accessory Packs used to be called a Language Interface Packs, which separated them from the language packs, that only provided spelling and grammatical checks only.

Answer (score 1):

To change the display language of Office :

- Run any Office application and select menu *File > Options > Language*
- Under "Office display Language", ensure that English is listed,
  or use "Add a language" to add
- Click "English"
- Click "Set as Preferred".

Reference :
[Change the language Office uses in its menus and proofing tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-language-office-uses-in-its-menus-and-proofing-tools-f5c54ff9-a6fa-4348-a43c-760e7ef148f8).